# How to configure an Avid Speed Dial brake

Tags: brakes

I got this [brake lever](https://www.sram.com/avid/products/speed-dial-7) on my new bike and I am looking help how to configure this. I do not know what purpose the red screw has on the top I reckon this has something to do with the name "Speed Dial" but I cannot figure it out, neither on Google nor on YouTube. I just get shopping links but nothing like an instruction.

Since this is the first time I am using a disc brake I would like to know if the back small wheel (where the brake cable comes in) has the same purpose as it has using V-Brakes?

Comment: Read what it says: Our patented Speed Dial® leverage adjustment system lets you determine the perfect balance between power and modulation of your linear pull rim or mechanical disc brakes. We’ve put the ability to change the cable’s leverage point into an easy-to-adjust knob on the front of the lever. By turning the Speed Dial® knob, you can precisely choose the feel you want anytime, anywhere and without any tools.

Comment: @DanielRHicks Per my answer below, I assumed the red lever was the Reach Adjust. They describe this under the "Technologies" tab, and they also describe the "Speed Dial", but I don't see an actual diagram telling you which knob is Speed Dial and which is Reach Adjust. Any thoughts on my answer?

Comment: *into an easy-to-adjust knob on the front of the lever*.  "Reach adjust" is the old mundane adjustments you get by playing with the cable adjuster and the little adjustment screw -- pretty much every lever has these, in some form.

Comment: Gotcha. After reading a bit more carefully, I saw the same line you quoted here. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Avid does provide a user manual for the Speed Dial 7 that describes what the different adjusters do. Just google 'avid speed dial 7 manual':

https://sram-cdn-pull-zone-gsdesign.netdna-ssl.com/cdn/farfuture/Bv5FmtpDsTVHw9CpVeB-YkdnOyinFNaPxEkOXTgCQdA/mtime:1372788167/sites/default/files/techdocs/speed-dial-7-install.pdf

Sometimes you just have to go old school and read the manual, rather than looking for someone to explain it on YouTube  :-)

From the diagram in the user guide one can see that the adjustment moves the attachment point of the cable to change how much cable is pulled for per unit of lever pull.

At one extreme the caliper will engage quickly, but more force on the lever will be required, and less modulation control will be available (will be harder to stop the wheel locking); at the other end the brake will engage more slowly, but you will need less force on the lever and modulation will be easier.

Comment: That link is dead, but there is a bootleg here: https://nuxx.net/files/bicycle/avid/speed-dial-7-install.pdf

Answer (score 4):

[image]

- **Reach Adjustment** - Set screw brings lever closer or farther away from the bar.
- **Barrel Adjuster** - allows you to adjust brake cable tension.
- **"Speed Dial"** - change leverage (i.e., lever throw vs cable pull).

Comment: I didn't see any answer that had all three adjustments in one post. The other answers do a better job at explaining these adjustment in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

The big black dial is your standard inline cable tension adjustment, so yes, the same as a normal V-Brake.

Based on the description [here](https://www.sram.com/avid/technologies/speed-dial), it appears the red dial is the "Speed Dial" adjustment outlined below. If I understand correctly, this is for changing modulation so the same lever can be used with either linear pull cantilevers or disc brakes.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're describing "speed dial", not "reach adjust".

Comment: Re use of cantis v linear brakes. If that was the case the lever would have 2 positions, not a range of adjustment.